# Compute pairwise geospatial distance matrix using GeoPandas

Tags: geopandas, distance-matrix

I have a large array that has user IDs and their respective geospatial locations at different times. I am trying to rank these users in terms of their geospatial activity; that is, how much each user moves around, on average. Hence, I am trying to compute a distance matrix for each user that computes their pairwise distances for each of their locations. I have a geometry column in my geospatial dataframe already, and I'm hoping that there is an efficient method (i.e., not cycling through each entry and computing gdf.geometry.distance(entry) over and over) to compute the pairwise distances from each entry in the geometry column to every other entry in the geometry column. Any ideas?

Comment: would the area polygon of all of a user's locations be a good metric for this?

Comment: Yes, this could be a good idea; I'll give it a try, Thanks!